# Loop accumulating results for linear plot

Tags: python, list, loops, matplotlib

I've been trying to solve this hard for couple of days, but no luck due to my limited understanding. Any insight will be very appreciable.

Basically, I have a loop. When I plot results, it overlays each other. 
[image]

However, what I want it plotting them linearly. Something like this.
[image]

My current code is below. Thank you for you help in advance.

```
import numpy as np
rate           = 0.07
saving         = 2000
year           = [1, 2, 4, 6]

for x in year:
    month          = np.arange(1,12*x+1,1)
    compound       = (1+rate/12)**month
    monthly_saving = saving*np.ones(np.size(month))
    monthly_growth = compound*monthly_saving
    total_growth = np.cumsum(monthly_growth)

    import itertools
    list2d = [total_growth]
    merged = list(itertools.chain(*list2d))

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(np.arange(1,np.size(merged)+1)/12, merged)

plt.xlabel("year")
plt.ylabel("asset")
plt.show()
```

Comment: fix indentation? imports at top too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed series

```
import numpy as np
#  import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


rate           = 0.07
saving         = 2000
year           = [1, 2, 4, 6]

merged = []                                      # init merge
for x in year:
    month          = np.arange(1,12*x+1,1)
    compound       = (1+rate/12)**month
    monthly_saving = saving*np.ones(np.size(month))
    monthly_growth = compound*monthly_saving
    total_growth = np.cumsum(monthly_growth)

    list2d = list(total_growth)                  # convert tolist
    merged.extend(list2d)                        # extend list

plt.plot(np.arange(1,len(merged)+1)/12, merged)  # plot once

plt.xlabel("year")
plt.ylabel("asset")
plt.show()
```

Comment: @ f5r5e5d, Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Really appreciate your help.